# how ambiguity of following grammar cant be decidable?

Tags: compilers, ambiguity, gate-cs

SO According to question grammar should be like this (A -> AA ).
->So i learn that if grammar is left and right recursive both then that grammar must be ambiguous but here the answer is deferent. Plz explain me.....Thanks :)
[image]

Comment: "Ambiguous grammar" means that there are multiple derivation trees for some input. It may be the case that no tree is derivable from `A`, meaning no ambiguity.

Comment: @Dmitry Make an answer?